# Closing popup removes Navbar

Tags: popup, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, close

I have an `esri popup` in my web app `MapView`:

```
  // Add the map to a MapView
  const view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",
            map: map,
            center: [-82.9001, 32.1656],
            zoom: 8,
            popup: {
                //actions: [risk_snapshot],
                actions: [],
                dockEnabled: true,
                dockOptions: {
                    buttonEnabled: true,
                    breakpoint: false
                }
            }
  });
  ...
  view.popup.open({
        // Set the popup's title to the coordinates of the clicked location
        title: "Location Coordinates: [" + lon + ", " + lat + "]",
        location: event.mapPoint, // Set the location of the popup to the clicked location
        content: setContentInfo(view.center, view.scale),
        actions: [risk_snapshot]
  });
```

I also have a simple `Bootstrap` Navbar in my app:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-dark bg-dark" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapibleMenu">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" style="color: cornflowerblue;">GA Map Viewer</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapibleMenu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#" style="color: cornflowerblue;">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div id="viewDiv"></div>
```

For some reason, whenever, I close the popup, the navbar disappears. Any reason why this would happen or suggestions on how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this was simple; although it still moves the view down whenever the popup closes. But it creates a scroll on the right, allowing the user to scroll up and makes the navbar visible again. Basically, the change I made was to add `fixed-top` to the class.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
```